# iMacros - How to Extract the first 100 Characters from a `TAG CONTENT`?

Tags: regex, extract, imacros, letter

I am using this code in iMacros to extract only the first 100 characters from `TAG CONTENT` and it's working in 80% of the cases, but sometimes iMacros displays an error message:

"**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'join'), line: 27**"
(Line 27 in iMacros Code is where the code is executed.)

=> **My question**:
Is there another way to do this, another Regex code, or did I do something wrong with the script below?

```scala
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:title EXTRACT=TXT
SET titlu100 EVAL("var x=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; x=x.match(/^.{100}/).join(''); x;")
```

---

**I am using (FCI):**
`iMacros for CR v10.1.1 'PE', CR v105.0.5195.102 (_x64), Win10_x64.`
('CR' = 'Chrome' / 'PE' = 'Personal Edition')

Comment: Like mentioned as a "final" Comment on your previous Qt (Question): "Mini-Detail, I see that you've already opened 2 new Threads, I haven't had a look yet, but hum, any chance you could read the iMacros Tag wiki...?, I "normally" don't answer when FCI is not included in a Post/Qt... (so I was "nice" for this one), + correct Spelling is "iMacros"... :idea: " URL for iMacros Tag Wiki: /imacros/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found another way to extract first 100 characters

```
SET titlu100 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".substr(0,100);")
```

Comment: Yep, very good..., was one of the ways I would have posted also..., but `substr()` would also be my "best choice"... (Was waiting for you to add your FCI to your Question...) // Be "careful" btw with the Space after "eval", some Version had "problems" with it, a few years ago... + Should use All_Capitals for iMacros Commands, per "Convention", => `EVAL()`...

Comment: Thank you for help.. About FCI I am not yet sure how to do it.. I made some changes on this post, can you please check it?  I want for future to understand how to write good threads. Thank you

Comment: Well, 'FCI' is all explained in the iMacros Tag [Wiki](/tags/imacros/info) (= "Full Config Info"): => iMacros Version + 'Free'/'PE'/'Pro'/'Ent'/'Trial' + Browser Version + OS. // + No "big deal", but again, correct Spelling is "iMacros" (only Capital is the "M"), you seem to like/use quite some JavaScript, and while "pure" iMacros Commands are Case-insensitive (but the Convention is to use All_Caps), JS Commands are Case-sensitive on the contrary, so you can better pay attention to Case-sensitivity "from the beginning" or you'll often run into Syntax Errors from a missing or misplaced Capital.

Comment: I got it now about FCI, thank you. I will update the post later.